# Why "this" in a jQuery plugin is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

¡Hi!

I'm trying to do a jQuery plugin but when I try to get the text of a element and repeat it, the plugin does it to every element on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fn.codigo = function() {
            this.append(this.text());
        };

    $(function() {
        $('.esto').codigo();
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="esto">1</div>
<div class="esto">2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will return:

> 112 212

But I just want it to return this:

> 11 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be because `this` refers to the *collection* of elements matched by the selector.

You want to `each` over it and handle them individually:

```
$.fn.codigo = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        var $t = $(this);
        $t.text($t.text()+$t.text());
    }):
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return` the jQuery collection for chainability.

Answer (score 3):

Write your plugin like this

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.codigo = function() {
    return this.each(function(idx, elem) {
      $(elem).text(function(idx, str) {
        return str + str;
      });
    });
  };

})(jQuery);
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5a4r1e4u/)

Check out the [.text(fn) API](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) — `fn` receives `index` of element and `str` set to the existing text. The returned value of the function sets the new text.

---

The above represents your pretty standard jQuery Plugin boilerplate. However, if this is the real goal of your plugin, you can simplify it a bit more.

```
jQuery.fn.codigo = function() {
    return this.text(function(idx, str) { return str + str; });
};
```

This will be quite fast as it's minimizing function calls by quite a bit (compared to other solutions provided here).

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the edit. I'm very flattered to have you look at one of my answers so closely ^.^

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is called once with the list of elements that you apply it to, not once for each element. Thus `this` is a jQuery object with all the elements.

Loop through the elements and apply the code to each one, and to make a nice plugin also return `this` so that it can be chained:

```
$.fn.codigo = function() {
  return this.each(function(i, e){
    $(e).append($(e).text());
  })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in your plugin is a jquery collection containing multiple elements.  I think that you want instead is the following:

```
 $.fn.codigo = function() {
     this.each(function(){
         $(this).append($(this).text());
     });
     return this;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please try  this one  because  this is very easy and good one concept........
Please you check at-least  one time this one concept..........

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.fn.codigo = function() {
                this.append(this.text());
            };

        $(function() {
            $('.esto').each(function(){
                $(this).append($(this).text());
                });
        });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="esto">1</div>
    <div class="esto">2</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```